# Is 1 Samuel 22:1-4 record of David asking King of Moab to look after his parents evidence that David had some affinity towards Moabite ethnic group?

Tags: 1-samuel, ruth, love, family

I might be indicating the obvious, but I suppose I say this because I myself come from an ethnic group with an Eastern cultural background, therefore, I am somewhat familiar with close affinities between families in the Eastern world.

King David is an Israelite, and more specifically traces his roots to the tribe of Judah, but his Moab ethnic lineage background is also recorded, and there seems to be some affinity expressed between David and the King of Moab because since David was fleeing from King Saul, he decided to ask the King of Moab to look after his parents since he was in exile.

> Ruth 4:13-17
>
> **13 So Boaz took Ruth, and she became his wife, and he went in to her.
> And the Lord [a]enabled her to conceive, and she gave birth to a son.**
> 14 Then the women said to Naomi, “Blessed is the Lord who has not left
> you without a redeemer today, and may his name [c]become famous in
> Israel. 15 May he also be to you a restorer of life and a sustainer of
> your old age; for your daughter-in-law, who loves you and is better to
> you than seven sons, has given birth to him.” **16 Then Naomi took the
> child [e]and laid him in her lap, and became his nurse. 17 The
> neighbor women gave him a name, saying, “A son has been born to
> Naomi!” So they named him Obed. He is the father of Jesse, the father
> of David.**

> 1 Samuel 22:1-4
>
> 1 So David departed from there and escaped to the cave of Adullam;
> and when his brothers and all his father’s household heard of it, they
> went down there to him..........................................
> ........................................
> **3 And David went from there to Mizpah of Moab; and he said to the king
> of Moab, “Please let my father and my mother come and stay with you
> until I know what God will do for me.”** 4 Then he left them with the
> king of Moab; and they stayed with him all the time that David was in
> the stronghold.

Is 1 Samuel 22:1-4 recorded event of David asking King of Moab to look after his parents since he was in fleeing King Saul does show that David had some kind of affinity to the Moabite ethnic group since his ancestor is Ruth the Moabitess?

Answer (score 1):

Later in 2 Samuel 8:2

> David also defeated the **Moabites**. He made them lie down on the ground and measured them off with a length of cord. Every two lengths of them were put to death, and the third length was allowed to live. So the **Moabites** became subject to David and brought him tribute.

Is 1 Samuel 22:1-4 record of David asking King of Moab to look after his parents evidence that David had some affinity towards Moabite ethnic group?

I doubt it. There were two reasons. The first one was proximity. The second one was that they had a common enemy: Saul.

1 Samuel 14:47

> After **Saul** had assumed rule over Israel, he fought against their enemies on every side: **Moab**, the Ammonites, Edom, the kings of Zobah, and the Philistines. Wherever he turned, he inflicted punishment on them.